# Electron - Access DOM elements in a loaded document using remote url

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

For example i want to load a remote address like `https://google.com` in a window but when a button in DOM is clicked, i want to call a function in main processor.

How to add click listener on a loaded document in `webview` or `iframe` to communicate `MainProcessor` ?

Edit: actually i don't have direct access to the source code of ducument because it is loaded from a remote url.

Comment: Have a look at https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Comment: @JeffProd question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefered to use `webview` and i set `preload` tag on the webview based on the link below and every thing works as expected.
[Github issues page](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2048)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) and [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) to pass a message between your processes.

Inside your web view

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

document.getElementById('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipc.send('click', '#myDiv');
});
```

Inside your main process.

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipc.on('click', (event, message) => {
    console.log(message); // logs out "#myDiv"
})
```

Comment: i mean i dont' have access to the document to write javascript code because it is loaded via remote url